# how to read excel file with nested columns with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I am trying to read an Excel file using pandas but my columns and index are changed:

```py
df = pd.read_excel('Assignment.xlsx',sheet_name='Assignment',index_col=0)
```

Excel file:

[image: excel file ss]

Jupyter notebook:

[image: jupyter notebook ss]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default pandas consider first row as header. You need to tell that take 2 rows as header.

```
df = pd.read_excel("xyz.xlsx",  header=[0,1], usecols = "A:I", skiprows=[0])
```

print df

You can choose to mention skiprows depending on the requirement. If you remove skiprows, it will show first row header without any unnamed entries.

Refer this [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html)

Comment: i tried it but it gives the error:Passed header=[0,1] are too many rows for this multi_index of columns

Comment: ok it worked somewhat I I got this   https://ibb.co/7JDWbTJ .How can I combine power and temperature under the header of registration unit-1?

Comment: @sanjuatwal try to skiprows=[1]

Comment: super thumbs up.